# Infinite Scrolling for Multiple Columns?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll, multiple-columns

I have a single php/html page site which consists of 4 div columns. All 4 of them are pulling the results from their specific tables in the MySQL database, and all of them are quite long. I decided to go for an infinite scroll solution, but the problem is that all of the scripts I've found refer to scrolling only a single div to which results are appended.

So I figured maybe with a bit of customizing it should be possible to make it work for multiple columns. I've decided to give this a go: https://github.com/tournasdim/PHP-infinite-scrolling . I've tried changing values and adding multiple sources of queries and then append them to different divs, but I'm not too sure how should I take on this.

This is from custom_jquery.js :

```
$.ajax({
dataType : "html" ,
url: "jquery-loadMoreComments.php?lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr('id') ,  
success: function(html) {
 doMouseWheel = 1 ; 
if(html){
$("#postedComments").append(html);
//console.log("Append html--------- " +$(".postedComment:first").attr('id'));
//console.log("Append html--------- " +$(".postedComment:last").attr('id'));
$("#last").remove();
$("#postedComments").append( "<p id='last'></p>" );
$('div#loadMoreComments').hide();
}else{      
$('div#loadMoreComments').replaceWith("<center><h1 style='color:red'>End of countries !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to take on this one?

Any insights given would be highly appreciated!

Also if you know another script that works better out of the box or needs fewer modification it's welcomed.

I currently use CodeIgniter to pull the results from the database and display them on the page, but because it's one simple page, I could also do it without CodeIgniter.

Comment: Will all 4 columns always be the same height?

Comment: Since all columns load their results from a database which is dynamic (managed separately through an admin panel) the number of the items inside will often change. So, no they won't be the same height.

Comment: @Jules Copeland what if they are same height? Is there a solution to it if they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it quick and dirty by just binding the scroll event to four Ajax calls, using different ids, but that will be very inefficient.

Especially if it checks all four columns even when you know that one has run out of new content.

Ideally, you should combine all four calls into one, then split the response accordingly.

Without seeing more code, I can't really help much, but that should be a starting point.

Comment: Since my project was simple and didn't load a lot of results, I did it the quick and dirty way as you suggested. Called the script 4 times. I know it's inefficient, but I don't have time to rewrite it for one call.